# A Very Short Wordsquare Riddle

Tags: riddle, word-square

> My first is a musical choir
>   My second is solid, a large one
>   My third consists only of zeroes
>   My fourth has just quickly run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my best attempt so far.

> `B A N D`
> `A S I A`
> `N I L S`
> `D A S H`